# Why i get a NullPointerException when I try to get a fragment from fragmentManager in Android Test?

Tags: android-fragments, android-testing, android-espresso

Hello I'm a newbie in Android testing. I was trying to check if a button is visible in my app during the UI test. I write something:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

@Before
public void setUp() {
}

@Test
public void clickOnProductTest() {
    if (isRegisterClosed()) {
        openRegister();
    }
    onView(withText("Food")).perform(click());
    onView(withText("Mineral water")).perform(click());
}

private boolean isRegisterClosed() {
    MainActivity activity = mRule.getActivity();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();

    Fragment f = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.current_order_fragment);

    View v = f.getView();

    Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.orderOpenRegister);
    return b.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}

private void openRegister() {
    onView(withId(R.id.orderOpenRegister)).perform(click());
}
```

On line

> View v = f.getView(); //in method isRegisterClosed()

I get NullPointerException. It looks like a fragment didn't load. But i don't know why. But when I try to click on button in that Fragment, it works:

> onView(withId(R.id.orderOpenRegister)).perform(click());

I want to do something like:

```
if (buttonIsVisible) {
      do smth;
}
else {
      do smth else;
}
```

This button is in current_order_fragment and its ID is orderOpenRegister.

### Edit

I find out, that I should add the following line:

> fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

so my method looks like:

```
private boolean isRegisterClosed() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        Fragment f  = fragmentManager
                      .findFragmentById(R.id.current_order_fragment);
        View v = f.getView();
        Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.orderOpenRegister);
        return b.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}
```

but if I do that, i need to run this test in UI thread. Does anyone know how to run test on UI thread?

Answer (score 3):

You can run the test in UI thread as below

```
Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();

instrumentation.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() { //your test
  }
});
```